# Can't set new original values to child element

Tags: html, css

I have dropdown menu, but child navigation takes all css settings from parent nav. Can I make it that it won't take anything and will show as unset element?

Structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>something</li>
  <li>something
    <ul>
      <li>submenu1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Most properties are inherited. You can unset them by defining them again to the child like say: `font-weight: unset;`

Comment: @pol, see https://jsfiddle.net/rs0tvn9m/.  Note that color is not unset (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Sometimes `initial` needs to be used. I've never needed to cancel properties like this.

Comment: `initial` works well for resetting individual properties.  Unfortunately, `all: initial` doesn't work so well:  https://jsfiddle.net/rs0tvn9m/1/.  Note that the submenu is no longer a "submenu."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these properties directly through the parent element of the outer `ul`. Like this:

```
li { // standard properties 
color: black;
}
.menu > ul > li { // properties only for the outer li elements 
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add it with the "nth-child" .

before I explain this to you,You know that the html document is nested so i can choose any child of any tag that i want

the usage of the nth-child is like that

[the tag] : nth-child([the number of the child the i want to style])

Here an example (you will use css) :-

```
<style>
ul li:nth-child(3) {
color: #FAF0F0;
background-color: black ;
width: 50px;
height: 10px;
}
```

This will change the third li child from ul ONLY and will not change the others [ beacuse i wrote nth-child(3) ]
and will make it to a #FAF0F0 color, Black background color, 50px width, 10px height.

so with th nth-child class you will be able to style any element of the html document.

i hope that you understand it :)